# Dart - markdown formatting after building to js

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am building a simple blog page where I wish to use markdown as the text format.
I have a working page when running in Dartium but when I compile to js the markdown does not come out properly formatted. It's missing paragraphs only I think but headers and lists are working fine.

I'm displaying the blog post in a polymer element and reading in a simple file from the server. I have made a simple sample without polymer which seems to work fine but I haven't tried it on the production server.

The basic code is outlined below, any tips or a better way of doing this? I will eventually move the posts to a db as text but I'm open to suggestions for other ways of presenting blog posts with some simple formatting, thanks.

```dart
getPostsFromServer(){
    String path = 'post1.md';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req
    ..open('GET', path)
    ..onLoadEnd.listen((e) => printPost(req))
    ..send('');
}

void printPost(HttpRequest req){
    var postdiv = $['article'];
    if(req.status == 200){
        var postText = req.responseText;
        print(postText);
        postdiv.innerHtml = markdownToHtml(postText);
    }
    else{
        postdiv.innerHtml = 'Failed to load newsletter, sorry.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the developer tools console if there are any error messages?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Günter, I'm relatively new to client side so using these tools isn't my natural go to.
I found that it was my css mucking things up, something I wouldn't have thought about but through the development console I could tweak some css and see the results. 
I am using a 'sticky footer' and having
    * {
        margin: 0;
    }

set was cramping the text somehow.
cheers.

Comment: No prob, glad I could help.